# How to design class inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I provide 3 interface classes for others IA, IB, IC。 and then I need to implement these 3 interface classes. My implementation method is as follows, but the behavior of a() in the 3 classes is the same, how can I reuse the code。

```
class IA{
    virtual void a() = 0;
};

class IB : public IA{
    virtual void b() = 0;
};

class IC: public IA{
    virtual void c() = 0;
};


class A :public IA{
    void a(){}
};

class B :public IB{
    void a(){}
    void b(){}
};

class C :public IC{
    void a(){}
    void c(){}
};
```

Comment: Are `IB` and `IC` really inheriting from/extending `IA`? Despite that answer you may want to take a look at "abstract classes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways:

- Create the common functions:

  ```
  void f() { /*..*/ }

  class A : public IA{
      void a() override { f(); }
  };

  class B : public IB{
      void a() override { f(); }
      void b() override { /**/ }
  };

  class C : public IC{
      void a() override { f(); }
      void c() override { /**/ }
  };
  ```
- use virtual inheritance

  ```
  class IB : public virtual IA{
      virtual void b() = 0;
  };

  class IC : public virtual IA{
      virtual void c() = 0;
  };


  class A : public virtual IA{
      void a() override { /*..*/ }
  };

  class B : public A, public IB{
      void b() override { /**/ }
  };

  class C : public A, public IC{
      void c() override { /**/ }
  };
  ```
- Use template/CRTP

  ```
  template </*typename Derived,*/ typename Base>
  struct AImpl : public Base
  {
      void a() override { /*..*/ }
  };

  class A : public AImpl</*A,*/ IA> {
  };

  class B : public AImpl</*B,*/ IB> {
      void b() override { /**/ }
  };

  class C : public AImpl</*C,*/ IC> {
      void c() override { /**/ }
  };
  ```
- Use composition

  ```
  class A : public IA{
      void a() override { /**/ }
  };

  class B : public IB{
      void a() override { mA.a(); }
      void b() override { /**/ }
  private:
      A a;
  };

  class C : public IC{
      void a() override { mA.a(); }
      void c() override { /**/ }
  private:
      A a;
  };
  ```